Conditions on the weak * convergence to be strong.
I know, thanks to Brezis, that on uniformly convex Banach spaces we have that the strong convergence is equivalent to weak convergence and the convergence of norms.
I cannot find anything comparable for the weak-* convergence.
I would like a reference for the following statement if present in the literature:

Given a separable Banach space $B$, what condition do I need to add to a weak-* converging sequence in a Banach space $B^*$ that also converge in norm so that it convergence strongly?

If such a statement is too general and thus has no answer I would be happy to find it in the context of $B^*=L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$

An easy necessary and sufficient condition is that the sequence has values in a norm-compact set.

@MichaelGreinecker that sounds very tautological: "A sequence converges strongly if and only if it is contained in a compact set and has a limit". The support of a converging sequence together with its limit is trivially compact.

It is very easy, though your argument is not quite complete. You still need the fact that the weak* topology is coarser than the norm topology and that it is a Hausdorff topology, which is not trivial.
